# TreeNode.EndEdit vs NodeLabelEditEventArgs.CancelEdit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

What is the difference between `TreeNode.EndEdit` and setting `NodeLabelEditEventArgs.CancelEdit`?

Answer (score 7):

Well, on the surface, calling `EndEdit(true)` indeed appears to do the same thing as issuing `e.CancelEdit = true` in an [AfterLabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterlabeledit.aspx) or [BeforeLabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforelabeledit.aspx) event handler. However, the two approaches are not equivalent, and are not used for the same purpose.

Best to demonstrate with an actual behavior example:

They do the same thing, because:

- If you call `EndEdit(true)`, the tree node will leave edit mode and discard changes,
- If you issue `e.CancelEdit = true` during `AfterLabelEdit`, the tree node will leave edit mode and discard changes.

But they're not equivalent, because:

- If you *don't* call `EndEdit(true)`, the tree node edit mode will *not* change (obviously),
- If you *don't* issue `e.CancelEdit = true` during `AfterLabelEdit`, the tree node will *still* leave edit mode (and commit changes),
- If you *don't* issue `e.CancelEdit = true` during `BeforeLabelEdit`, the tree node will *still* enter edit mode.

Another difference is that `EndEdit()` triggers `AfterLabelEdit`, but `AfterLabelEdit` doesn't recursively trigger itself (fortunately).

Now, usually [NodeLabelEditEventArgs.CancelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nodelabelediteventargs.canceledit%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is used for validation, i.e. to discard invalid modifications to the tree node label (during `AfterLabelEdit`) or to completely prevent the user from editing the labels of some nodes (during `BeforeLabelEdit`). In both cases, the user has either already finished or has not yet started editing the label.

[EndEdit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.endedit.aspx) is supposed to be used to forcibly commit or cancel editing *while the user is still editing the label*. Of course, that means `EndEdit(false)` is *evil* and *wrong*, because it commits a potentially breaking change *before* the user has finished typing and *without* his consent. So, I've never seen it called that way, actually.

Calling `EndEdit(true)` to discard the current edit might be useful if something else *absolutely requires* the focus *right now* and you don't want to autocommit the incomplete edit when the tree node loses focus. Throwing away your user's work that way is still rude, though.

Back in the MFC days, there was a legitimate use for the `EndEdit(true)` equivalent: cancel editing when the user pressed the `ESC` key. Believe it or not, that feature wasn't supported out of the box in MFC at that time (and maybe still isn't today, I didn't check).

But nowadays, there's not much use left for `EndEdit()` in my opinion. Better let it rest in peace.

Comment: Evil or not, I had to call EndEdit when I was going to the top menu and my node was not leaving the edit mode. IMHO, that's the main difference between them: you can call EndEdit from everywhere, while you cannot use CancelEdit if AfterLabelEdit not triggered yet.